# Using one stack to find number of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have a **stack** and I want to find the **permutations** of numbers 1,2,3,...n.

I can push and pop. e.g. if n=2: push,pop,push,pop 1,2 and push,push,pop,pop 2,1

if **n=4 I can only get 14** from the 24 permutations using the stack.. Does anyone know any function F(n) that could produce the number of permutations the stack **(only one)** can produce? 
eg f(1)=1

f(2)=2

f(4)=14

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

The number corresponds to the [Catalan Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) which are of the form $\displaystyle \frac{{2n \choose n}}{n+1}$.

I believe this particular problem is an exercise Knuth's Art of Programming Volume I.

For a hint of proof: Number of pushes $\ge$ Number of pops in any prefix of the string of pushes and pops.